# Problema con NavBar "brinca" al hacer Scroll (shrink)

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Añadi CSS y con JQuery hago que cuando el usuario hace scroll, la NavBar se "comprima" junto con el logo, el problema es que cuando se hace scroll la navBar hace un comportamiento raro y "brinca". ¿como puedo arreglar ese detalle?

[Enlace al código en acción](https://codepen.io/isidromar95/pen/pZGvwB)

[image: Gif del Problema]

y me gustaría que se pudiera "comprimir" como la navbar de este sitio [Sitio ejemplo](https://doemee.zoetermeer.nl/home/default.aspx)

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: por eso puse el enlace a codePen, ahí está mi código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Cambia el `position: sticky` por `position: fixed` y añade un `width: 100%` a tu navbar en tu archivo CSS:

  ```
  .navbar {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%
  }
  ```
- Quita la clase `sticky-top` de tu navbar.
- Puesto que `position: fixed`, a diferencia de sticky, saca al elemento del flujo del documento, tienes que darle un margen vertical al contenido. "Envuelve" tu contenido en un `div` con una clase, digamos, `.content`, y añade

  ```
  .content {
      margin-top: 220px
  }
  ```

  a tu archivo CSS.

Y... eso es todo. Dado que ahora el navbar está fuera del flujo del documento, su animación no cambia el valor del `scrollTop` de la ventana, lo que sí hace cuando está con el valor de `sticky` en la posición. Al no haber cambio de valor, la animación en sí no dispara el evento `scroll`, y no se produce el "rebote".

Comment: ¡Gracias!, justo lo que buscaba. muchas gracias y tu explicación clara y concisa. problema resulto

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo con esta funcion `debounce`.  Algo asi:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
    $(window).scroll(debounce(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

         //>=, not <=
        if (scroll >= 50) {
            //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
             $(".navbar-brand").addClass("navbar-shrink");
             $(".navbar").addClass("nav-shrink");
            $(".logo-navbar").addClass("img-shrink");
        }
      else{
        $(".logo-navbar").removeClass("img-shrink");
         $(".navbar").removeClass("nav-shrink");
         $(".navbar-brand").removeClass("navbar-shrink");

      }
    }, 25));
```

Comment: ya lo probé y sigue igual.